# Does Google Chrome create a new socket for every HTTP request?

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, http

I am writing a web server, specifically, a server that handles `HTTP/1.0` and `HTTP/1.1` protocols. I implemented `HTTP/1.0` features in my server and wanted to look at persistent HTTP connections (`Connection: Keep-Alive`). I also implemented that feature and tested the server via `telnet`. Everything works fine for telnet, the server does not close the client socket after every request, waits for 15 seconds, and closes the socket if it is inactive.

To ensure that it works correctly, I re-tested the server with Postman. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see from the logs, the socket connection is not dropped after sending the response. After 15 seconds of inactivity, the server closes the socket. This is the **desired** behavior

However, when I used the Google Chrome web browser, it turns out that it does not work correctly (not the same with the desired behavior). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I speculate that Google Chrome creates a new socket connection for every request even though Connection: Keep-Alive is present in both HTTP request/response messages. However, I am not sure whether this is true or not. By the way, I also used Safari and the output is the same.

Is this the reason why persistent HTTP connection does not work in Google, yet it works with telnet and Postman?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of 'Google', call it 'Chrome' or 'Google Chrome' which is the common name. This confused me because I thought this was about GoogleBot.

Comment: Google Chrome keeps connections open. What you see is likely an artifact of how you do the testing. Unfortunately you only present results and don't explain how these results where exactly obtained, so one cannot point out what exactly causes this behavior. For example if you forcible reload the site, then it might create a new connection for this.

Comment: Ah, yes. I reloaded the site for testing. That might be the issue. Thanks for pointing that out @SteffenUllrich!!!